# How to know which next attribute is requested in python

Tags: python

I have class with custom getter, so I have situations when I need to use my custom getter, and situations when I need to use default.

So consider following.

If I call method of object c in this way:

```
c.somePyClassProp
```

In that case I need to call custom getter, and getter will return int value, not Python object.
But if I call method on this way:

```
c.somePyClassProp.getAttributes()
```

In this case I need to use default setter, and first return need to be Python object, and then we need to call getAttributes method of returned python object (from c.somePyClassProp).
Note that somePyClassProp is actually property of class which is another Python class instance.

So, is there any way in Python on which we can know whether some other methods will be called after first method call?

Comment: The only possible way to do what you want is to make `c.somePyClassProp` return an object that combines (part or all) of the two interfaces you want. That is, you'd need it to be something that looks like an `int` but also has a `getAttributes` method. If you need it to be able to do anything non-trivial, it will be messy and complicated. Are you sure you can't use a different method or property name to separate the two uses?

Comment: Kindall's answer seems to be the best, but only if you're okay with an object that behaves as an int in all contexts **except** it also supports the getAttributes method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to return different values based on which attribute is accessed next, you want to return an `int`-like object that *also* has the required attribute on it. To do this, we create a subclass of `int` that has a `getAttributes()` method. An instance of this class, of course, needs to know what object it is "bound" to, that is, what object its `getAttributes()` method should refer to, so we'll add this to the constructor.

```
class bound_int(int):
    def __new__(cls, value, obj):
        val = int.__new__(cls, value)
        val.obj = obj
        return val
    def getAttributes(self):
        return self.obj.somePyClassProp
```

Now in your getter for `c.somePyClassProp`, instead of returning an integer, you return a `bound_int` and pass it a reference to the object its `getAttributes()` method needs to know about (here I'll just have it refer to `self`, the object it's being returned from):

```
@property
def somePyClassProp(self):
   return bound_int(42, self)
```

This way, if you use `c.somePyPclassProp` as an `int`, it acts just like any other `int`, because it is one, but if you want to further call `getAttributes()` on it, you can do that,  too. It's the same value in both cases; it just has been built to fulfill both purposes. This approach can be adapted to pretty much any problem of this type.

Comment: While this technically works, it's horribly confusing. A `bound_int` with an int value of 3 will print as `3` and look almost exactly like a real `3`, but it'll fail `type` checks and cause memory leaks if the `bound_int` is kept around longer than the object it was created from. You don't want to debug a memory leak caused by something that looks like a `3`.

Comment: It passes type checks fine as long as you do them the right way, i.e., with `issubclass()`. Your other concern, while not technically a memory leak, is a good point and something to be aware of if the object being referred to is large. There are a lot of circumstances where the `bound_int` will go away entirely, averting this issue, but a lot of other circumstances where it doesn't.

Comment: You could use a `weakref.ref` to store the reference to the other object, to avoid forcing it to hang around in memory after it's otherwise needed.

Comment: A weakref would shorten the lifetime of whatever the `bound_int` is bound to, but probably too far. `create_temporary().somePyClassProp.getAttributes()` would be an error. If you were to use one of these `bound_int`s, you would have to be very, very careful about reference lifetime. I can't see any way it'd be worthwhile.

Answer (score 4):

No. `c.someMethod` is a self-contained expression; its evaluation cannot be influenced by the context in which the result will be used. If it were possible to achieve what you want, this would be the result:

```
x = c.someMethod
c.someMethod.getAttributes() # Works!
x.getAttributes()            # AttributeError!
```

This would be confusing as hell.

Don't try to make `c.someMethod` behave differently depending on what will be done with it, and if possible, don't make `c.someMethod` a method call at all. People will expect `c.someMethod` to return a bound method object that can then be called to execute the method; just `def`ine the method the usual way and call it with `c.someMethod()`.

Comment: Tnx on your answer. Actually in my case 'someMethod' isn't method, it is other Python class, so, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want two ways to get the property depending on what you want to do with it. I don't think there's any inherent Pythonic way to implement this, and you therefore need to store a variable or property name for each case. Maybe:

```
c.somePyClassProp
```

can be used in the `__get__` and
    `c.somePyClassProp__getAttributes()`
can be implemented in a more custom way inside the `__getattribute__` function.

One way I've used (which is probably not the best) is to check for that exact variable name:

```
def __getattribute__(self, var_name):
    if ('__' in var_name):
        var_name, method = var_name.split('__')
    return object.__getattribute__(self, var_name).__getattribute__(method)
```

Using `object.__get__(self, var_name)` uses the object class's method of getting a property directly.

Comment: Sorry that was a whole mess, should use the `__getattribute__` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the contained python object as a variable and the create getters via the @property dectorator for whatever values you want. When you want to read the int, reference the property. When you want the contained object, use its variable name instead.

```
class SomePyClass(object):
    def getInt(self):
        return 1
    def getAttributes(self):
        return 'a b c'

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, py_class):
        self._py_class = py_class

    @property
    def some_property(self):
        return self._py_class.getInt()

x = MyClass(SomePyClass())
y = self.some_property
x._py_class.getAttributes()
```